# Large chunks of data from database to be sent as the web service API response

Tags: mysql, ruby, web-services, webserver, sinatra-activerecord

We are using Ruby version 2.0.0 as programming language and Sinatra as framework and MYSQL for database activity. This application is mainly to create web service APIs. 
We have a requirement to create a "GET API" which accepts the request from client and fetch records from our table based on the client request and return the fetched records as response to the client in json format.

The result obtained from table are large chunks of data which takes long time to fetch from table and this when sent as response to API results in "Time out error" or "Memory leakage error".

Our table is always large and our "get api" is always dealing with large chunks of data from table.

How can I make the query execution faster and send the large chunks of data as response to the client in json format, in an efficient way?

Please help me out with possible solutions.

Here is my table description :

+------------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+

| Field                      | Type             | Null | Key | Default |

+------------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+

| id                         | int(11)          | NO   | PRI  | NULL    |

| AccountID                  | varchar(255)     | NO   | MUL  | NULL    |

| ApplyURL                   | varchar(1024)    | YES  |      | NULL

| CityName                   | varchar(64)      | YES  |      | NULL

| ClassList                  | varchar(5000)    | YES  |      | NULL

| CompanyDID                 | varchar(20)      | YES  |      | NULL

| ContactCompany             | varchar(64)      | YES  |      | NULL

| ContactEmail               | varchar(512)     | YES  |      | NULL

| ContactFax                 | varchar(32)      | YES  |      | NULL

| ContactName                | varchar(64)      | YES  |      | NULL

| ContactPhone               | varchar(100)     | YES  |      | NULL

| CountryName                | char(2)          | NO   | MUL  | NULL

| DTCreated                  | datetime         | NO   | MUL  | NULL

| DTModified                 | datetime         | NO   | MUL  | NULL

| DTSysCreated               | datetime         | NO   | MUL | NULL

| DTSysModified              | datetime         | NO   | MUL | NULL

| DegreeCode                 | varchar(200)     | YES  |     | NULL

| DegreeCodeDecoded          | varchar(1024)    | YES  |     | NULL

| DisplayCity                | varchar(64)      | YES  |     | NULL

| DisplayJobID               | varchar(32)      | YES  |     | NULL

| ExperienceCode             | varchar(200)     | YES  |     | NULL

| ExperienceCodeDecoded      | varchar(1024)    | YES  |     | NULL

| ExternalKey                | varchar(32)      | YES  |     | NULL

| GeoUSZip5                  | varchar(5)       | YES  |     | NULL

| HostSite                   | char(2)          | NO   | MUL | NULL

| IndustryCode               | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL

| IndustryCodeDecoded        | varchar(1024)    | YES  |     | NULL

| IsBOFJob                   | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | NULL

| IsDiversityJob             | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | NULL

| JobDID                     | varchar(20)      | NO   | MUL | NULL

| jobdesc                    | text             | YES  |     | NULL

| JobFunctionCode            | varchar(1024)    | YES  |     | NULL

| JobFunctionCodeDecoded     | varchar(1024)    | YES  |     | NULL

| JobReq                     | text             | YES  |     | NULL

| JobSkinDID                 | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL

| JobTitle                   | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL

| JobType                    | varchar(1024)    | YES  |     | NULL

| JobTypeDesc                | varchar(1024)    | YES  |     | NULL

| JobTypeCodeDecoded         | varchar(1024)    | YES  |     | NULL

| LocLatitude                | decimal(10,5)    | YES  |     | NULL

| LocLongitude               | decimal(10,5)    | YES  |     | NULL

| Location                   | varchar(70)      | YES  |     | NULL

| ManagementCode             | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL

| MaxExp                     | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL

| MinExp                     | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL

| Onet                       | varchar(10)      | YES  |     | NULL

| OnetTitle                  | varchar(200)     | YES  |     | NULL

| PRBeginDate                | datetime         | NO   | MUL | NULL

| PREndDate                  | datetime         | NO   | MUL | NULL

| PayBaseH                   | decimal(10,2)    | YES  |     | NULL

| PayBaseL                   | decimal(10,2)    | YES  |     | NULL

| PayBonus                   | decimal(10,2)    | YES  |     | NULL

| PayComm                    | decimal(10,2)    | YES  |     | NULL

| PayOther                   | varchar(64)      | YES  |     | NULL

| PayPer                     | varchar(8)       | YES  |     | NULL

| PayType                    | char(3)          | YES  |     | NULL

| PostalCode                 | varchar(10)      | YES  |     | NULL

| PostingPath                | varchar(20)      | NO   | MUL | NULL

| Relocate                   | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | NULL

| RelocateOptions            | varchar(5)       | YES  |     | NULL

| ScreenerDID                | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL

| SiteID                     | varchar(1024)    | YES  |     | NULL

| SliceList                  | varchar(10000)   | YES  |     | NULL

| StateName                  | char(30)         | YES  |     | NULL

| Status                     | varchar(50)      | NO   | MUL | NULL

| TextPay                    | varchar(40)      | YES  |     | NULL

| TotalPay                   | decimal(10,2)    | YES  |     | NULL

| TownName                   | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL

| TravelCode                 | varchar(200)     | YES  |     | NULL

| TravelCodeDecoded          | varchar(1024)    | YES  |     | NULL

| UpgradeList                | varchar(64)      | YES  |     | NULL

+------------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

My sql query :

**select * from exportjobs where Status = 'Active' And HostSite = 'WR' And UPGRADELIST NOT In ("JCPRV0", "JCINT0", "JCSOLPRI0", "JSSLL0", "JNSOLPRI0", "JCPRI0ML", "JCBAS0JS")**

Comment: Is your query slow? Can it be optimised? How much is "large chunks"? Cutting out ActiveRecord and directly using `mysql2` gem might help a lot, too.

Comment: @Amadan  It takes time to fetch record from table on  performing "SELECT" query with "WHERE clause", as my table contains more than 700k rows.

"large chunks" is around 600k rows as result which has to be sent as response to api client in json format.

could you please explain in detail how can i directly use mysql2 gem,? Thanks.

Comment: MySQL is very, very efficient, and 700k rows in a table is nothing. It all depends on what your query is, and how much data is touched by the query. Post your query, post your table schema, and post your `DESCRIBE`; then we can talk about optimisation. Also, did you check whether the delay is in SQL (as reported by the ActiveRecord debug output) or outside it?

Comment: You can also increase the timeouts. It is reasonable for an API request to take a lot of time for a lot of data.

Comment: @Vatev, yes it is reasonable for API taking lot of time for large data. Is there any solution for handling large chunks of data in response, like asynchronous web service?